# Scrollable Table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Is there any good and light jQuery plugin out there make Scrollable Tables.

I got one at http://www.webtoolkit.info/scrollable-html-table-plugin-for-jquery.html but that won't working non-IE and non-FF browsers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for light code, skip the jQuery altogether and use pure HTML/CSS:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Header Item 1</th><th>Header Item 2</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><th>Footer Item 1</th><th>Footer Item 2</th></tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody style="overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; height: 100px;">
        <tr><td>Item 1-1</td><td>Item 2-1</td></tr>
        ...
        <tr><td>Item 1-N</td><td>Item 2-N</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The key is in setting the overflow CSS in tbody, so as to make that part scrollable (but not the entire table).  You'll also need to set the height, so you can define how tall the scrollable section should be.

Comment: Keep in mind that this does not a "cross browser" compatible solution.  This will not work in Internet Explorer 7 or below or Safari.

Comment: Ugh, seriously?  Yet another reason to add to the list of reasons I despise IE.  Won't someone think of the standards: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3

Comment: In IE8 they had removed setExpression so that it won't works in IE8.It will thow error that the setexpression() is not implemented. Is there any solution to work in IE8?

Comment: @Allen Can you please provide the way you got the solution?

Comment: I had to add 'display:block' for thead and tbody to make it work :-)

Comment: This doesn't work without 'display: block', and 'display: block' adds a variety of problems and complications.  Please test your code before sharing advice that doesn't work.

Comment: I know it's a necroposting, but setting "overflow: scroll" and fixed height for <tbody> still doesn't work in any of A+ browsers in mid-2013. So this answer doesn't really answer, because the solution presented will work only in fairyland, at least for now.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one that works well:
http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-scrollable-table-plugin/

And since it was mentioned above, here's a pure HTML/CSS cross-browser solution:
http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

Comment: I found the jQuery version, too, but it seems too buggy to use in a production environment. Too bad, because it's really nice.

Comment: Wow your 2nd link works great in FF but fails in IE, doh! I'd say their "•IE 6.x +" is incorrect. It is from 2004 I guess.

Comment: I, too, ran across this plugin.  I found that it can cause column alignment issues and other visual bugs, especially with complex tables having row and column spans.  This plugin is probably only good for uncomplicated matrix-style tables.

Comment: Since posting this I've actually started using the method used by Twitter Bootstrap 3: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive. It's not JQuery based, but seems to work best (for what I need it for anyway) in the greatest number of browsers..