# How do i create html table with fixed header and scrollable body?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, html

I have an html table. I want to set table header as fixed and table body as scrollable..  How can i do this...? Advance thanks...

Answer (score 2):

[Scrollable Table using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583102/scrollable-table-using-jquery). Check whether is this your question?

Comment: It's not work on Chrome.